# using the chain rule for f(x,y)

Tags: calculus

I have 2 questions about the following chain rule:
Lets assume that $f,g,u,v$ are diffrentiable. If  $g(x,y)=f(u(x,y),v(x,y))$, then $$g_x=f_{u}\cdot u_x+f_v\cdot v_x $$

1. I don't understand what doest $f_u$ means, For example: if I know that $f(x,y)$ satisfies that $f_x(2,3)=7$ then that means $f_u(2,3)=7?$, What is $f_u $ exactly?
2. If $g(x,y)=f(x^2-y,y^2-x)$ and we want to find $g_x$

I tried to convince someone that the following solution is wrong: $u=x^2-y,v=y^2-x$ and $f(u,v)$ is diffrentiable because $f(x,y) $ is diffrentiable,I think that the problem here is that you can't say it. The solution I offered is define $x=u^2-v,y=v^2-u$ and then find $g_u$, so who is wrong?

Comment: If you call the inputs of $f$ by the names $u$ and $v$, so you write $f(u,v)$, then $f_u$ is the partial derivative with respect to the first input. If you call them $x$ and $y$ then you write $f(x,y)$ and call the same partial derivative $f_x$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The function $f_u$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with regard to the first variable, meaning $$f_u = \frac{\partial }{\partial u} f(u,v).$$
2. To calculate $g_x$, just plug $u(x,y) = x^2-y$ and $v(x,y) = y^2-x$ into $g_x = f_uu-x + f_vv_x$.